# how to load new data from api using RefreshIndicator

Tags: api, flutter, async-await, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image]

```
Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    try {
      final newItems = await ApiServices.fetchArticleList(pageKey, _pageSize);

      final isLastPage = newItems.length < _pageSize;
      if (isLastPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + newItems.length;
        _pagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      _pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }
```

so, i have method _fetchPage() that loads data from api initially, but on refresh new data are not updated in screen. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i have tried using
```
Future<void> _pullRefresh(BuildContext context) async {
    return await _fetchPage(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `onRefresh` callback to

```
onRefresh:()=>_fetchPage(0)
```

`_fetchPage` method in your code is expecting a parameter but you are not passing the value. since the `onRefresh` callback doesn't have any value to pass as parameter to the function

Comment: i have passed 0 as a parameter

Comment: My point was to use the full function call instead of method reference. Pass any valid key as parameter

Comment: i did as you suggested, still UI isnot being updated

Comment: Does the api called on refresh?